# Laravel 8.x: Still refering to the 'users' table despite being changed into custom 'corehub_users'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am stuck with a weird problem. I have one project which i am trying to convert a legacy php project to a laravel project. The user table is called corehub_users and i made changes to the project file so that it will refer 'corehub_users' instead of 'users'. This is working fine in my local host but when i copied the exact folder to the remote server and made the following  changes in

1. Auth.php

```
'users' => [
    'driver' => 'database',
    'table' => 'corehub_users',
],
],
```

2. .env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=corehub_testportal
DB_USERNAME=corehub_user
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

and made sure the right database is pointed in database.php file. Despite all these changes it is throwing the following exception

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` = myloom@gmail.com)
```

Can you help how can i debug this or what may the problem here. It is working perfectly in pc the problem is only in the server.

Comment: run `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: @KamleshPaul I did that. Do i need to copy the entire project directory again to the server?

Comment: did you have `protected $table = 'corehub_users';` in your User Model?

Comment: Yes i have that @ArturCapraro

Comment: Make sure your .env is getting read on server.

Comment: @PrashantDeshmukh.....It is getting read because it is not saying it is not able to connect to the database, it is just saying its  not able to find the table

Comment: i think in your user model add protected $table='core_hub_user'; then it will work fine

Comment: It is already present  protected $table = 'corehub_users'. As i mentioned it is all working fine in the local server and i copied the exact directory to the server

Comment: did you check .env file on server because i had same problem like this when i check .env file it was still same not same as local then i copied .env file to server so worked fine

Comment: yes, i did, is there any way to echo the database it is trying to conect to?

Comment: by the way the login route is correctly picking 'corehub_users'. The registration route is picking 'users'

Comment: @logeeks is there any project in server before you copied there

Comment: No. Everything was cleared before it was copied

Comment: did you change User model name in Model   and 'driver' => 'eloquent',
    'model' => App\Corehub_user::class in config/auth.php too,

Answer (score 0):

I dont know it will work for you or not exactly but there is little thing in Register controller

```
protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            //'firstname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            //'lastname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            //'middlename' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            //'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:6', 'confirmed'],
            //'image' => ['required', 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif','max:10000'],
        ]);
    }
```

here change email column `unique:corehub_users` then it will be like this

```
protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            //'firstname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            //'lastname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            //'middlename' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:corehub_users'],
            //'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:6', 'confirmed'],
            //'image' => ['required', 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif','max:10000'],
        ]);
    }
```

By the way this example is from my project dont care other column just change email